# How to escape ?(Question Mark) in prepared statement of hive query?

Tags: java, hive, hiveql

I have the following hive table-

`hive> desc table_group_special_character_3;`

```
OK
column_?                int
column_2                int
Time taken: 2.084 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Through code, we run hive queries to fetch the result. For the above table while executing `"select column_?,column_2 from table_group_special_character_3;"` I get the following exception-
"parameter #1 is unset".
I know for sure that this is happening as my column name is column_?(post removing it is working).

I would like to know how to escape ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When special characters are present as a part of the column name in Hive table, you can use the symbol ` around the column name to select the column.

For your question, you can run a query like the below in Hive,

```
select `column_?`,column_2 from table_group_special_character_3;
```

Hope this helps!